# SQL Need Help formatting a table with leading zeroes into a decimal

Tags: sql

My Results set is below. Basically i want to select this column and remove the leading zeroes and decimal along with the space. So my result set would come back as 60.0 86.7 only etc.

I tried a LTRIM to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

```
 0.00 60.0
 0.00 60.0
 0.00 60.0
 0.00 60.0
 0.00 60.0
 0.00 60.0
 0.00 86.7
 0.00 60.0
 0.00 60.0
 0.00  0.0
 0.00 60.0
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using the **REPLACE()** function to replace it with nothing.  This function is available in MySQL, SQL Server, and Oracle ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ecdcfb/3/0)):

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(FieldName, '0.00 ', '') AS DECIMAL(4,2))
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Can this be used in a SELECT? I want to write a query that anytime i pull that field is returned wihtot the leading zeroes/spaces or decimal.

Comment: **user3723180**, yes you can use it in a `SELECT` statement.  See my edit.  Note that I am also casting the result of the `REPLACE` function as a `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT RIGHT(column_Name, LEN(column_Name)-5) FROM Table_Name
```

Comment: **@Dinesh Reddy**, just a note.  `LEN` is not a function in MySQL or Oracle.  For MySQL or Oracle use `LENGTH()`.  Oracle does not have `RIGHT` either.  I am only mentioning this since the OP did not specify which database they were using.

Comment: ok,thanks for saying that @Linger but i was thought that it was for MSSQL server

Comment: This worked great! Thanks! Sorry i did not specify i am using SQL